# google chart api data asp.net

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, charts, google-visualization

I created a graph with the help of google chart api and I have a problem with correct display name of the month on the chart e.g. 2017-02 or 2017-03.

[My Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i0C6G.png)

My code in controller looks like:

```
public ActionResult ListOrder()
    {


        var result = from s in db.Orders.ToList()
                     group s by
                         new { Year = s.dateCreated.Year, Month = s.dateCreated.Month, Day = 1 }
                         into g
                         select new OrderViewModel
                         {
                             dateCreated = new DateTime(g.Key.Year, g.Key.Month, g.Key.Day),
                             TotalPrice = g.Sum(x => x.totalPrice)
                         };
        return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

[My code in view looks like](http://pastebin.com/rEPS0MVE)

Any help or suggestion is welcome. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in order to format the axis labels, the x-axis values must be actual dates, not strings

the integer from the string can be used to get the proper date

-- convert first column to actual date

from: `"/Date(1483225200000)/"`

to: `new Date(1483225200000)`

```
// change column data type to 'date'
data.addColumn('date', 'Month');
data.addColumn('number', 'Total sum order for month');

for (var i = 0; i < chartData.length; i++) {
    var rowDate;

    // convert dateCreated
    rowDate = chartData[i].dateCreated;

    // replace first forward slash (/) with 'new'
    rowDate = rowDate.replace('/', 'new ');

    // remove second forward slash (/)
    rowDate = rowDate.replace('/', '');

    // evaluate the string to an actual date
    rowDate = eval(rowDate);

    data.addRow([rowDate, chartData[i].TotalPrice]);
}
```

---

once actual dates are in place, the format can be set in the chart options...

```
hAxis: {
  format: 'yyyy-MM'
}
```